# invite friends from address book sample example xcode ios

Tags: ios, xcode, addressbook

need to invite my friends in my app.
I am getting email,phone number and names but not in proper.need to get each and every contact with respect to name.if name is not available show a blank space.data should be displayed in tableview.

Comment: when you say "invite", what do you mean?  send e-mail invitations to them or invite them to Facebook or somewhere else?

Comment: "Invite from address book" Do you actually want to send a custom message to the user or email invite or facebook invite?

Comment: hi everyone thanks for reply..i got the answer.i want the screen to be displayed like    this.But i have a question when i click on select all..then each and every cell should  be selected..as of now am able to perform single and multiple selection but am not able to select all .

Comment: unfortunately my image is not displayed here because of no reputations.